# How to Send 2D array through php cURL

Tags: php, python, curl, multidimensional-array

I'm working with a a distributed system where a php app sends a post request to a python app.

My code is pretty straight forward:

```
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    
$output=curl_exec($ch);
```

I have a 2d php array that looks like:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["a"]=> 'aaa' ["token"]=> string(55) "146bf00b2cb8709" } [1]=> array(2) { ["a"]=> string(52) "bbb" ["token"]=> string(55) "146bf00b2cb96e74302" } [2]=> array(2) { ["a"]=> string(52) "ccc" ["token"]=> string(55) "146bf00b2cb96e6c422417" } }
```

I want to transmit this via php curl, but I'm not sure how to do this in a way that is decodable on the other end in python.

Comment: Set the request body to be a JSON encoded string and then read it as JSON in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## php

```
// 2d array
$arr = array(array(1,2,3),array(4,5,6),array(7,8,9));
// 2d array into json
$json = json_encode($arr) // [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
send($json)
```

## python

```
import json
r = request.body # receives request from php
json = json.loads(r)
print json[0] # [1,2,3]
```

Comment: You're getting me a lot closer. I have a follow up at TypeError: expected string or buffer decoding json in flask

Comment: you have to get the request into string format, try `str(request.body)`

Comment: Tried that, but did not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336554/typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer-decoding-json-in-flask.

Comment: Its not 100%, but 90% helps a lot. Thanks for showing me the way.

Answer (score 0):

> `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);`

Will encode your request as an HTTP query and transform your data into a *multipart/form-data*.

The python application must be an HTTP server and be able to receive this request. The decoding will be done by the HTTP framework/module.

Comment: The downvote is not legit as OP did not say what python http server he is using nor in which format should the data (json/form-data/urlencoded) transit ...

Comment: @Cyrbil yeah but the thing is this is a universal issue, when connecting to anything other than php with curl. and its not a curl problem ether its a php issue due to how php arrays work and how http requests work. $_POST is great for new guys and its all good when a request is mapped into php as a simple array but we cant map it back to a http post body for some reason because php doesn't support the same key being used more than once and everything that has a multi select using the same key when it comes to http requests universally