# TypeError: expected string or buffer decoding json in flask

Tags: php, python, json, curl

I'm working with a a distributed system where a php app sends a post request to a python flask app.

I have a 2d php array  ($data) that looks like:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["a"]=> 'aaa' ["token"]=> string(55) "146bf00b2cb8709" } [1]=> array(2) { ["a"]=> string(52) "bbb" ["token"]=> string(55) "146bf00b2cb96e74302" } [2]=> array(2) { ["a"]=> string(52) "ccc" ["token"]=> string(55) "146bf00b2cb96e6c422417" } }
```

following [How to Send 2D array through php cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335668/how-to-send-2d-array-through-php-curl?noredirect=1#32335775)

I have:

```
$json =  json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    
$output=curl_exec($ch);
```

In flask, my code is:

```
@app.route('/index',methods=['POST'])
def index():

    import json
    r = request # receives request from php
    json = json.loads(r.form)
```

and I can see that the request is coming through as JSON:

```
>>> r.form
Out[12]: ImmutableMultiDict([('[{"a":"aaa","token":"146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab3f7daa11c55e4bc6eb5f2d5.46266037"},{"a":"bbb","token":"decdbc1691816cae83392e2a379a2c2555e4bc60df5f86.89400754"},{"a":"ccc","token":"146bf00b2cb96e6c425c2ab3f7daa11c55e4bc6e039320.76477875"}]', u'')])
```

But I can't seem to get it into a parsable form. I' getting the error above. How can I access this JSON string?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.get_json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@app.route('/index',methods=['POST'])
def index():
    json = request.get_json()
```

Comment: json = request.get_json(force=True) worked for me. Thank you very much.